# Unable to ready body after parsing headers

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I have been working on a http server, when I am trying to read the body part of the request It just gets stuck in there, here are snippets of my code

This part reads until headers and calls the parser

```
void Connection::start_operation() {
  parser_ = new Parser(shared_from_this());
  if (sock_.is_open()) {
    //! TODO limit header size
    asio::async_read_until(
        sock_, request_stream_, "\r\n\r\n",
        [me = shared_from_this()](system::error_code ec, const size_t bytes) {
          if (!ec && bytes) {
            std::unique_ptr<char> req(new char[bytes]);
            me->input_stream.read(req.get(), bytes);
            me->parser_->parser_init(std::string(req.get()));
          } else {
            error::print(ec);
            return;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

The parser makes the call to `read_body` on parsing `Content-Length` Field

```
  template <typename Callback>
  void Connection::internal_read_body(std::string &req, size_t bytes, Callback call) {
    std::unique_ptr<char> buff_space(new char[BUFFER_SIZE]);
    if (sock_.is_open()) {
      std::cout << "Here" << std::endl;
      sock_.async_read_some(
          boost::asio::buffer(buff_space.get(), BUFFER_SIZE),
          [me_ = shared_from_this(), bytes, &req, buff_space = std::move(buff_space), call](
              boost::system::error_code ec, const size_t &bytes_read) mutable {
            std::cout << "$$$ " << buff_space.get() << std::endl;
            req.append(buff_space.get(), bytes_read);
            bytes -= bytes_read;
            if (bytes > 0)
              me_->internal_read_body(req, bytes, call);
            else
              call();
          });
    }
  }
    
    void Connection::read_left_over(std::string &req, size_t &bytes) {
      std::string extra_data;
      input_stream >> extra_data;
      bytes -= size_t(extra_data.size());
      req.append(std::move(extra_data));
    }
    
template <typename Callback>
  void read_body(std::string &req, size_t bytes, Callback call) {
    // reserve so much space in the string
    req.reserve(bytes);
    // reading from remaining data in the streambuf
    read_left_over(req, bytes);
    ioc_.dispatch(
        [this, &req, bytes, call] {
          internal_read_body(req, bytes, call);
        });
  }
```

The code is stuck in the `async_read_some` after printing "Here", I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, or how to debug through this issue. Any help or hint on the cause of error would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `&bytes` in capture list of lambda inside `async_read_some` leads to undefined behaviour, because `bytes` is local inside `internal_lead_body`, you have dangling reference. `bytes = std::move(bytes)` doesn't make any sense for plain data, just capture it by value `[.., bytes, ..]`.

Comment: The same goes for the other reference captures in the same lambda, all end up as dangling (apart from maybe `req`? depends on how `read_body` is called)

Comment: @rafix07 I have fixed the dangling references but still no luck with getting the body. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: In the lambda of `start_operation()`, `std::unique_ptr<char> req(new char[bytes]);` is wrong, it needs to use `<char[]>` instead (same with `buff_space` in `internal_read_body()`). Better to use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` instead (especially since `parser_init()` takes a `std::string` anyway). In any case, `Content-Length` is not the only way to determine the length/end of an HTTP message, see [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for mentioning those issues, but the real issue lies in `internal_read_body()` stuck after printing out "Hello" and then gets stuck in `async_read_some`.

Comment: For some reason my `sock.available()` always is zero even when I call in `start_operation` which successfully reads header data, which is really absurd. Not sure what to make out of this